# Merging two dataframes in pandas without column names (new to pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

**Short explanation**:

If you have duplicate column names in your data, be sure to rename one column when you read the file.

If you have `NaN` etc in your data, remove those.

Then merge using correct answer below.

---

Probably a pretty simple question.

I have two datasets that I read in using `pandas.read_csv()`.

My data is in two separate csv.

With the following code:

```
        import mibian
        import pandas as pd


        underlying = pd.read_csv("txt1.csv", names=['dt1','price']);

        options = pd.read_csv("txt2.txt", names=['dt2','ticker','maturity','strike','cP','px','strike','yield','rF','T','rlzd10']);

        merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='dt1', right_on='dt2');
```

My two data heads look like this:

```
>>> underlying.head();

          0         1
0  20040326  3.579987
1  20040329  3.690494
2  20040330  3.755247
3  20040331  3.719373
4  20040401  3.728671
```

and

```
>>> options.head();

         0     1         2     3     4      5     6   7      8         9                10

0  20130628  SVXY  20130817  32.5  call  39.22  32.5   0  0.005  0.136986   0.411224
```

So my column 0 on either data set is the key i want to merge on, and i want to keep all data from both result sets.

How would I go about doing this? All the examples I am finding online require keys, but I do not have that in my results.

But on the join I get the following errors:

```
                            Traceback (most recent call last):
                              File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
                              File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
                                execfile(filename, namespace)
                              File "/Users/jasonmellone/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 12, in <module>
                                merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='dt1', right_on='dt2',how='outer');
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3723, in merge
                                suffixes=suffixes, copy=copy)
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 40, in merge
                                return op.get_result()
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 197, in get_result
                                result_data = join_op.get_result()
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 722, in get_result
                                return BlockManager(result_blocks, self.result_axes)
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1954, in __init__
                                self._set_ref_locs(do_refs=True)
                              File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.13.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2091, in _set_ref_locs
                                'have _ref_locs set' % (block, labels))
                            AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [IntBlock: [dt1], 1 x 372145, dtype: int64] with duplicate items [Index([u'dt1', u'price', u'dt2', u'ticker', u'maturity', u'strike', u'cP', u'px', u'strike', u'yield', u'rF', u'T', u'rlzd10'], dtype='object')] does not have _ref_locs set
```

I searched through my data sets and there are no duplicates.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you do `underlying.drop_duplicates(cols='dt1',inplace=True)` and `options.drop_duplicates(cols='dt2',inplace=True)` does the merge work? Also do you have any `NaN` values?

Comment: If the problem still persists can you post links to the data so that I can download and have a look

Comment: @EdChum drop_duplicates causes the same error as the merge `AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [IntBlock:`.

Comment: I had a look at your data `svxySynthetic.csv` has unique values for `dt1` but `optionsArg` has duplicated values for `dt2` as you have one entry for `call` and another for `put`, and in fact out of 372032 rows, you only have 2411 unique `dt2` values so how do you want to merge these?

Comment: OK I see one of the problems, you have duplicate column names: change your line to this: `options = pd.read_csv("txt2.txt", names=['dt2','ticker','maturity','strike','cP','px','strike_1','yield','rF','T','rlzd10'])` and then decide how you want to merge the datasets

Comment: Or you can just skip that column as it seems to be redundant: `options = pd.read_csv("txt2.txt", names=['dt2','ticker','maturity','strike','cP','px','strike_1','yield','rF','T',‌​'rlzd10'], usecols=['dt2','ticker','maturity','strike','cP','px','yield','rF','T',‌​'rlzd10'])`

Comment: what if i join underlying to the option? i want the duplicate date lines actually, and just want the underlying price per date of the option. not the option price per day of the underlying. does that make sense?

Comment: If you swap the order and specify left join then it should work: `merged=options.merge(underlying, left_on'dt2', right_on'dt1', how='left')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50923/discussion-between-jason-m-and-edchum)

Comment: I suggest you delete your comment that shows your email address to stop potential spammers, glad my suggestions helped you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still be able to merge on the columns:

```
merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='0', right_on='0')
```

This will perform an inner merge so only the intersection of both datasets, i.e. where the values in column `0` exist in both, if you want all values, then specifcy `outer`:

```
merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='0', right_on='0', how='outer')

In [10]:  

merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='0', right_on='0', how='outer')

merged

Out[10]:

          0       1_x   1_y         2     3     4      5     6   7      8  \
0  20040326  3.579987   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN   
1  20040329  3.690494   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN   
2  20040330  3.755247   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN   
3  20040331  3.719373   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN   
4  20040401  3.728671   NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN NaN    NaN   
5  20130628       NaN  SVXY  20130817  32.5  call  39.22  32.5   0  0.005   

          9        10  
0       NaN       NaN  
1       NaN       NaN  
2       NaN       NaN  
3       NaN       NaN  
4       NaN       NaN  
5  0.136986  0.411224  

[6 rows x 12 columns]
```

You would have to rename or move the columns that clashed `1_x` and `1_y` above.

It is probably better to rename the columns to something sensible before hand.
When reading the csv you can pass a list of column names:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=['Id', 'Price'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue brought me to this thread.  I was ending up with a key error.  The fix was removing the single quotes from `left_on='0'` to `left_on=0`.

```
merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on='0', right_on='0')
merged = underlying.merge(options, left_on=0, right_on=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to use the same column for merging, which is true in your case, you can simply use `on=0` where `0` represents the first column in both dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
merged = underlying.merge(options, on=0, how='outer')
# or
merged = pd.merge(underlying, options, on=0, how='outer')
```

If the index column is different in both dataframes then you could use `left_on` and `right_on` onptions.

```
# here 0 is the index column for df1 and 2 is the index column for df2
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=0, right_on=2, how='outer')
```

Comment: That's not true actually when you have tons of csv/data file without a header. Also, it works great when you apply the same command over multiple files and their column names are different.